# TK Custom Map Polygon Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps, polygon

How can I make my polygon go throughout the street instead of the weird shape in the image below, the data I am passing have the street coordinates. so I don't know why it makes such a strange shape.
How could I fix this?

[image]

```
public async Task DisplayRoute (List<Position> rpositions, Color color)
        {


            Polygons = new ObservableCollection<TKPolygon>();

            var LoopB = new TKPolygon
            {
                StrokeColor = color,
                StrokeWidth = 4f,
                Coordinates = rpositions
            };

            _polygons.Add(firtline);
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            LoopB.StrokeColor = color;
            await Task.Delay(1000);



        }
```

Use this set of coordinates. how could they go through the streets instead of cutting the line through buildings and the sea?

```
25.848399-80.120878
25.850423-80.120287
25.85412-80.120397
25.85776-80.120689
```

Comment: First of all, please make sure you have set the correct postion, then i saw your screenshot, it seems like the Polyline. Can you share a demo about it?

Comment: And make sure your order of postion in `Coordinates=new List<TK.CustomMap.Position>()` If you order is wrong, the `Polygon` will be a mess. You can try to these postions, if you can get the rectangle. `new TK.CustomMap.Position(37.797513, -122.402058),
                new TK.CustomMap.Position(37.798433, -122.402256),
                new TK.CustomMap.Position(37.798582, -122.401071),
                new TK.CustomMap.Position(37.797658, -122.400888)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited the question.

Comment: Can you provide the routepositions? That i can test it for you.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I added some coordinates. thanks!

Comment: Did you call the Google Directions API to get the route postions?

Comment: No - However, I get it from another similar API